# Video playing, how to play a video back a a rapid rate at random timestamp locations

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg

Note: this is a mildly general question that is looking more for pointers in the right direction and not exactly requiring a concise coded answer. I appreciate any and all input, thank you for lending your brain power to me for this moment :)

I have a script that receives midi messages in real time and triggers playback of a single video on various timestamps that are changed/selected regularly and randomly by a user. Currently this is working in the browser, however, I've realized that there is some noticeable latency between (i'm guessing the cause here so please correct me) the moment a request to play a video at a specific time is made(note: the video is not being requested over the wire, this action does not take place until a JS Blob Url is loaded into the player) and the moment where that request is fulfilled and delivered from storage to pixels on the screen.

My question is: Is it reasonable to assume that there is a tool out there, that given the correct video format and optimizations both in the code and in the file that could load an entire, say: 1 gb video into memory and play it back at random timestamps every 60 milliseconds at completely random, constantly changing timestamps.

If you're now all the way down here... Thanks for reading this far, or scanning! Please let me know if this question makes any sense / could be improved, I'm happy to clarify further.

Comment: Are you limited to a specific format?

Comment: @llogan I am using mp4 currently but I'm definitely not married to that format, as long as its universal enough to distribute to a few clients. I was wondering if there is a format out there that indexes the frames more efficiently or does some kind of highly optimized dithering. I'm new to video technology so still very receptive to a suggestion. Thanks for the input!